# Error while fetching the files from sftp server using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, pscp

I'm trying to get *.xlsx files from the sftp server folder "/From/Outbound/TEST" using putty. I know it's something to do with the source path. I tried the below but nothing is working. Please please help.

```
"$Source/*.xlsx"
'$Source/*.xlsx'

$Source = "sftp@33.113.250.45:/From/Outbound/TEST"
[string]$TransferResults = & 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -l 'user' -pw 'password' $Source/*.xlsx  $Destination
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
pscp.exe : pscp: wildcard '*.xlsx' matched no files
At Test.ps1:29 char:31
+    [string]$TransferResults = & 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -l 'user' - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (pscp: wildcard '*.xlsx' matched no files:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: This error is from `pscp`. Perhaps this will be useful, see especially the update to the question (you're using PoSH 4, which is very old, so I wonder if the putty you are running is also old): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27419/how-to-use-wildcards-when-copying-with-scp

Comment: Does it work if you use hard-coded values instead of variables?

Comment: Also, double-check the case. *NIX filesystems are often case sensitive, so `file.Xlsx` and `file.xlsx` would be two different things.